# WaitGroup goroutines with channel

Tags: go

I am learning `WaitGroup` from the blog https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/02/15/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-executing-before-continuing/

the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    messages := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // you can also add these one at 
    // a time if you need to 

    wg.Add(3)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
        messages <- 1
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        messages <- 2
    }() 
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        messages <- 3
    }()
    go func() {
        for i := range messages {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

I think it should print 3, 2 and 1 in order. But it only prints 3, 2 but 1 is missing, what's the problem?

You can tree it on https://play.golang.org/p/kZCvDhykYM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right after the latest `messages <- 1`, the deferred `wg.Done()` is invoked which releases `wg.Wait()` in the end of the program and the program quits. When a program quits all the goroutines get killed, so the printing goroutine does not have a chance to print the latest value.

If you put something like `time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)` right after `wg.Done()` you would be able to see all the output lines.

Comment: Alternatively, make it `wg.Add(4)`, and put a `wg.Done()` in the print routine as well.  That said, personally I prefer to put the `wg.Wait()` in a goroutine and use a channel closure as the "done" signal: https://play.golang.org/p/o-EYS_fK2k

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    messages := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)

    // created this goroutine to wait for other
    // goroutines to complete and to close the channel
    go func() {
     wg.Wait()
     close(messages)
    }()

    go func() {
      defer wg.Done()
      time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
      messages <- 1
    }()

    go func() {
      defer wg.Done()
      time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
      messages <- 2
    }()

    go func() {
      defer wg.Done()
      time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
      messages <- 3
    }()

    // this for loop is blocked in main goroutine.
    // till it reads all messages and channel is closed.
    for v := range messages {
      fmt.Print(v)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned blog starts with following comment:

> EDIT: As pointed out by effenn in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/1y3spq/how_to_wait_for_all_goroutines_to_finish/cfh9fg7/) Reddit comment, a lot of information in this article is “dangerously inaccurate”. OOPS! I’ve written a followup/correction article [here](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/02/21/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-executing-before-continuing-part-two-fixing-my-ooops/) for your viewing pleasure, but I’m leaving this article up for “historical purposes”.

The [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/1y3spq/how_to_wait_for_all_goroutines_to_finish/cfh9fg7/) and the [followup article](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/02/21/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-executing-before-continuing-part-two-fixing-my-ooops/) both describe the problem and give a solution to your problem. (Adding `time.Sleep(...)` to make the program work the way you expect is really hacky...)

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    messages := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // you can also add these one at
    // a time if you need to

    wg.Add(3)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
        messages <- 1
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        messages <- 2
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        messages <- 3
    }()

exit:
    for {
        select {
        case i, ok := <-messages:
            if !ok {
                break exit
            }
            fmt.Println(i)
        default:
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```